# Rmarkdown HTML rendering issue

Tags: html, r, r-markdown, knitr, gtsummary

I am trying to print a list of HTML tables, but for some reason when I knit the document, I get the raw HTML code for output instead of the rendered table. Example:

```
---
title: "html-render-issue"
output: html_document
---
```

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

# this table renders correctly:
tbl_summary(iris)

# but this table does not!!
tables <- list(tbl_summary(iris), tbl_summary(cars))
print(tables)
```

I don't understand why this is happening, I tried indexing into the list with a for loop

```
for (i in 1:2) {
  print(tables[[i]])
}
```

but this doesn't seem to work either! Short of doing `tables[[1]]; tables[[2]]` etc. (which does work), is there a way to iterate over the list and get the output I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with adding `%>% as_gt()` within the list!

```
---
title: "html-render-issue"
output: html_document
---
```

````
```{r loop_print, results = 'asis'}
library(tidyverse)
library(gtsummary)

tables <- list(tbl_summary(iris), tbl_summary(cars) %>%  as_gt())
walk(tables, print)               # walk from purrr package to avoid [[1]] [[2]]
```
````

[image]

Comment: exactly what i was looking for thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Consider using `results = "asis"` in the `r` chunk and then instead of `print` use `knitr::knit_print`

````
```{r, results = "asis", echo = FALSE}
 library(gtsummary)

 # this table renders correctly:
 tbl_summary(iris)

 # but this table does not!!
 tables <- list(tbl_summary(iris), tbl_summary(cars))
 for (i in 1:2) {
   cat(knitr::knit_print(tables[[i]]))
 }
```
````

---

-output

[image]

Comment: Thanks akrun! Do you know what the issue with my original attempt is? I thought it has to do with the print() treating the argument as output instead of raw html. However, if I try to do `for (i in 1:2) tables[[i]]` I get nothing at all in the knitted output!

Comment: @HankLin according to `?knit_print` -`the chunk option render is a function that defaults to knit_print().`

Comment: surprisingly, the `cat()` after `knit_print()` is essential in some cases, e.g. when calling the .Rmd from `render()`. Any ideas why the `cat()` call is necessary?